# How to use ST Monad with monad transformers

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

The haskell `transformers` library provides `MonadIO` class and `liftIO` to lift IO operations in a monad transformer stack.  It seems to me that the same could be done for the ST monad, but I couldn't find it in any monad transformer library.  Is there a reason for this omission?  How do I use ST monad with e.g., `MaybeT` or `ReaderT`?

Comment: Relevant package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/STMonadTrans

Comment: I don't know of any `liftST` that can magically work on transformer stacks like `liftIO` does. Still, if there's no such magic around, we can still work using [`lift`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift). We need to apply `lift` once of each transformer in the stack, so it's not as convenient, but it should work.

Comment: What type would `liftST` have? The phantom type variable on ST seems to me like it would make things difficult.

Comment: @amalloy Interesting, but I wonder if that's really the case. I tried `lift (newSTRef "hello" >>= \r -> readSTRef r)` and GHCi typed it as `MonadTrans t => t (ST s) [Char]`. As long as we use a monad transformer stack on the base monad `ST s`, using the same `s` everywhere, I can see no obvious issues with one-step lifting. Regarding the more general `liftST`, perhaps it could be `liftST :: MonadST s m => ST s a -> m a` (note the `s` in the constraint)?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/eh2obw/something_like_stref_but_usable_in_a_monad/fcgmji9/

Answer (score 2):

I gave it a shot, and it looks like if you only want to use `ST` as a base monad, the following is probably sufficient for use with the "usual" transformers.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module TransST
  (liftST, MonadST)
  where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.RWS
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.ST

class Monad m => MonadST s m where
  liftST :: ST s a -> m a
instance MonadST s (ST s) where
  liftST act = act
instance (MonadST s m) => MonadST s (ReaderT r m) where
  liftST act = lift (liftST act)
instance (MonadST s m) => MonadST s (StateT st m) where
  liftST act = lift (liftST act)
instance (Monoid w, MonadST s m) => MonadST s (WriterT w m) where
  liftST act = lift (liftST act)
instance (Monoid w, MonadST s m) => MonadST s (RWST r w s m) where
  liftST act = lift (liftST act)
instance (MonadST s m) => MonadST s (MaybeT m) where
  liftST act = lift (liftST act)
instance (MonadST s m) => MonadST s (ExceptT e m) where
  liftST act = lift (liftST act)
```

You may find you occasionally need to add a type application to `liftST` or other functions to resolve ambiguous uses of the ST monad parameter, as in this test case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import TransST

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef
import Data.Char

type M s = ReaderT Int (WriterT [String] (StateT Char (ExceptT String (MaybeT (ST s)))))

runM :: (forall s. M s a) -> Int -> Char -> Maybe (Either String ((a, [String]), Char))
runM act r s = runST $ runMaybeT $ runExceptT
  $ flip runStateT s $ runWriterT $ runReaderT act r

someSTOperation :: (MonadST s m) => Int -> m (STRef s Int)
someSTOperation x = liftST (newSTRef x)

test :: Maybe (Either String ((Int, [String]), Char))
test = runM act 5 'a'
  where
    act :: forall s. M s Int
    act = do
      tell ["starting"]
      x <- gets ord
      s <- someSTOperation @s x  -- needs a type annotation
      r <- ask
      liftST (writeSTRef s (x + r))
      put . chr =<< liftST (readSTRef s)
      c <- get
      return (ord c)
```